# 1 College math competitions ranking

Tags: inequality, contest-math, fractions

Let $a,b,c,d$ be real numbers which are strictly positive.
Show that
$$1\lt\dfrac{a}{a+b+c}+\dfrac{b}{b+a+d}+\dfrac{c}{c+a+d}+\dfrac{d}{d+c+b}\lt2.$$ 
I need help please.

Comment: This is not how you are expected to ask questions here, I suggest you make an edit including your thoughts on the problem.

Answer (score 3):

No advanced techniques are necessary, just observe that 
$$
\frac{a}{a+b+c+d}<\frac{a}{a+b+c}<\frac{a}{a+b}.
$$

Comment: The trick is not to use this inequality cyclicly for each term, but to estimate $\frac{b}{b+a+d}<\frac{b}{a+b}$ to obtain exactly $2$ in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Because $1=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b+c+d}<\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b+c}<\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a+d}{a+b+c+d}=2$

Comment: i don't understand this answer

Comment: @mohamedzakariaeBoukour  What exactly? $1=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b+c+d}$, $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b+c+d}<\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b+c}$, $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b+c}<\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a+d}{a+b+c+d}$ or $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a+d}{a+b+c+d}=2$?

Comment: Michael Rozenberg ,i don't understand if this term ∑cycaa+b+c equivalent or equal aa+b+c+bb+a+d+cc+a+d+dd+c+b

Comment: Michael Rozenberg ,i don't understand if this term ∑cyc(a/a+b+c) equivalent or equal (a/a+b+c)+(b/b+a+d)+(c/c+a+d)+(d/d+c+b)

Comment: @mohamed zakariae Boukour Yes! $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b+c}=\frac{a}{a+b+c}+\frac{b}{b+c+d}+\frac{c}{c+d+a}+\frac{d}{d+a+b}$ and you can make a similar thing.